# UINavigationBar appearance crash in iOS 7.0

Tags: objective-c, ios7

```
        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {      
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:230.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:160.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
            >>EXC_BAD_ACCESS
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarBackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            return YES;
        }
```

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I'm doing a simple code that works fine in the iOS `7.1` but does not work in `7.0`

> Error: CGImageProviderCreate: invalid image provider size: 128 x 0.
>
> Error: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 128 x 0. Unable to create
>   image from csi bitmap data

navBarBackground located in `Media.xcassets`. Im using Xcode 5.1

**Any idea how to fix it?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved the problem. In this image in `Media.xcassets`, you must set the slicing at least by 1px
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tint the `UINavigationBar`, you have to use `setBarTintColor:`

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:230.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:160.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

**Edit:**

Your background image for the `UINavigationBar` has to have 320x64 pixels and need to be PNG.